# EXTRACT returns numeric instead double precision

Tags: sql, postgresql, time

I ran into a problem: on a local database, EXTRACT returns numeric, which causes an error because the backend cannot parse it to int. On the production database everything works well and returns double precision as it should. In the sql, everything is of type timestamp without time zone. With what such behavior can be connected? Some local setting?

```
select EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (finish_timestamp_p - answer_timestamp_p)) AS duration from ...
```

[image]

Comment: EXTRACT  return data type depends on Postgresql version

Comment: @Serg I didn't find it in the docs. Where can I see which version has which type of returned data

Comment: For example [v14](https://postgrespro.com/docs/postgrespro/14/functions-datetime#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) and [v9.6](https://postgrespro.com/docs/postgresql/9.6/functions-datetime#functions-datetime-extract)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return type of `EXTRACT` changed from `double precision` to `numeric` in PostgreSQL v14.

I can think of two solutions:

- add an explicit type cast:

  ```
  CAST (EXTRACT (....) AS integer)
  ```
- use `date_part` instead of `EXTRACT`, which still returns `double precision`